# how to add/append string data in xml using php

Tags: php, xml

The below is my sample xml data

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <book NAME="ci_id">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[55190]]></PVAL>
      </book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <book NAME="ci_id">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[55191]]></PVAL>
      </book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <book NAME="ci_id">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[55192]]></PVAL>
      </book>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
   </book>

   <book>
      <book NAME="ci_id">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[55194]]></PVAL>
      </book>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
   </book> 
</catalog>
```

my requirement is i have to remove parent node(i.e, < book > to < /book >) based on the pval id condition( ex: here i am deleting pval = 55192) and i need to update the new node.

In the below code i have successfully removed the parent node based on the pval, but i could not add the new node (i.e, its is a string value). Please guide me.

```
$xmlFileToLoad   =  'client_temp/endeca_xml_search_feed/product/testing.xml';
      $xmlFileToSave   =  'client_temp/endeca_xml_search_feed/product/testing-modified.xml';

      $cdata_text = '
      <book>
         <book NAME="ci_id">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[78965]]></PVAL>
         </book>
         <author>testing</author>
         <title>Md kaif khan</title>
         <genre>kkkk</genre>
         <price>5.95</price>
         <publish_date>2016-09-10</publish_date>
         <description>Just i am testing.</description>
      </book>';

      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->load($xmlFileToLoad);
      $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    function findStopPointByName($xml, $query) {
      $upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAZSCZCÓL";
      $lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazscznól";
      $arg_query    = "translate(text(), '$upper', '$lower')";
      $q = "//book[book/PVAL[contains($arg_query, '$query')]]" ."\n";
      return $xml->query($q);
    }

    foreach(findStopPointByName($xpath,'55192') as $node)
    {
      $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
       $node->appendChild( 
     $doc->createTextNode( $cdata_text ) );  
    }

    $dom->save($xmlFileToSave);
```

Please tell me how to add node (i.e,string data. here $cdata_text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   foreach(findStopPointByName($xpath,'55192') as $node)
    {
      // Save parent - after removing node we will use it
      $parent = $node->parentNode;
      $parent->removeChild($node);

      // Load XML from text. You cann't append text, only node
      $data = new DOMDocument();
      $data->loadXML($cdata_text);

      // Import all new XML to our one and append to saved parent
      $ndata =  $dom->importNode($data->documentElement, true);   
      $parent->appendChild($ndata); 
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi  @splash, I need ur help.
i am trying to add new node to the root node(i.e, <book>...</book>).
Using the following code. 
 `$newNode = new DOMDocument();
          $newNode->loadXML($trimData);
          $newNode->formatOutput = true;

          // Import all new XML to our one and append to saved parent
          $ndata =  $dom->importNode($newNode->documentElement, true);   
          $dom->documentElement->appendChild($ndata);`

Can you please help me on this

Comment: thanks for ur quick response.

while i am executing the above code, i get the **Fatal error:  Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object** 
Can you please tell me how to resolve this

Comment: change last line `$dom->appendChild($ndata);`;

Comment: Hi @slash,  Sorry to disturb to again, as i have changed the line $dom->appendChild($ndata) the new xml node(i.e, <book>...</book>) added successfully. But it is adding out-side of the root node(i.e, <catalog>). i Need to add the new node(i.e,<book>....</book> ) under the root node (i.e, <catalog>.....</catalog>).

Can you please help me out this

Comment: Hi @Slash, the code is working fine, but the performance is very poor. Example: It takes 55 seconds to complete for 10 nodes and the server load it too high, it took almost 99 percent.(i.,e <book>). Now i am not using findStopPointByName function. instead i am using $dom->getElementById(here record id. that is <book id=1>....</book>);  Can you please give me suggestion, that how to improve the performance.

Comment: Xpath is slow operation :( . What's about getElementById - it offen does not work in DomDocument library :( It depends of html document header. I try to don't use that method in php